# Vue error in Laravel blade: Property or method "type" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Would like some assistance on this error I am getting in Vue: Property or method "type" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Vue code:

```
Vue.component('content-text-area', {
        data() {
            return {
                type: document.getElementById('type').value
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
          console.log(this.type)
        },
        template: '<p>Testing</p>'
    })

    new Vue({ el: '#content-text-area-div' });
```

Blade code:

```
<div id="content-text-area-div">
      <content-text-area v-if="type === 'article'"></content-text-area>
</div>
```

Comment: and where is `type` prop in the main component?

Comment: @Anatoly thank you for the response. The "type" variable is defined within data in the component.

Comment: No that `type` is accessible `inside` the component and not outside.

Comment: Even if I add a div within the component, for example:
`
<div id="content-text-area-div">
                            <content-text-area>
                                <div v-if="type === 'article'">
                                    Test
                                </div></content-text-area>
                        </div>
` I still end up having the same error

Comment: That's right. You should declare `test` where you use it i.e. where you describe `<div id="content-text-area-div">`

Comment: So am I unable to use `type` that I have declared within the component `content-text-area` within a div that resides inside of the `<content-text-area>` tag?

Comment: For that you should use scoped slots https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

Comment: Thank you for that information. At the very least the error went away and now I just need to figure out how it works. I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 issues to fix here:

1. `type` should be defined in the parent component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#content-text-area-div',
  data() {
    type: '' // Initialize it here
  }
});
```

2. You can't refrence the DOM in `data`, as it is instantiated **before** the DOM is built. So you should read and assign the value in the [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) hook.
   See the [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

```js
mounted() {
  this.type = document.getElementById('type').value
}
```

Or even better (the "Vue way"):

```html
<input ref="type"/>
```

```js
mounted() {
  this.type = this.$refs.type.value;
}
```

See also: [Refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)